# Scala Yield behaves differently than Scala Map

Tags: arrays, list, scala, functional-programming, yield

I trying to compose and initialize an Array in a single line, roughly equivalent to this:

```
var characterMap = new Array[List[ActorRef]](sizeX*sizeY)
characterMap.indices.foreach(characterMap(_) = Nil)
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
var characterMap = ((0 until sizeX*sizeY) map Nil).toArray[List[ActorRef]]
```

But this does:

```
var characterMap = (for (_ <- 0 until sizeX*sizeY) yield Nil).toArray[List[ActorRef]]
```

I thought they were equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var characterMap = (for (_ <- 0 until sizeX*sizeY) yield Nil).toArray[List[ActorRef]]
```

Is translated into:

```
var characterMap = (0 until sizeX*sizeY).map(_ => Nil).toArray[List[ActorRef]]
```

and this should work.

Nit-picking: They are not equivalent, they are the same. `for` is just sugar syntax.

By the way, you might want to consider:

```
Array.fill[List[ActorRef]](sizeX*sizeY)(Nil)
```

Comment: I didn't realize ```Nil``` vs ```_=>Nil``` would make a difference! I was looking for the ```Array.fill```, but ```java.utils.Arrays.fill``` isn't quite the same ;) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a bit why your code wasn't working, and what it was actually doing.

```
val characterMap = ((0 until 10) map Nil)
```

I've simplified a bit to make it more comprehensible.

`(0 until 10)` is a `Range` object whose `map` method (as for others collections and such) expects a function of type `(A) => B`
where `A = Int` in our case

Since the typechecker is satisfied with `map Nil`, it looks like `Nil` must be a function `(Int) => B` in some way, could it be?

The point here is that `Nil(i: Int)` can be used as syntax sugar for `Nil.apply(i: Int)` which actually exists!

It's the generic sequential collection method to get the *i-th* element.

Running the above code tries to convert the range elements `(0,1,...,9)` to the corresponding indexed values of the `Nil` object, which is the empty `List`

Of course there's no element in the empty list, so an error is thrown, as shown

```
scala> val characterMap = ((0 until 10) map Nil)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    ...
```

### conclusion

`yield` and `map` have the same semantic meaning but slightly different syntactical rules.

While `yield` expects the result of the mapped function, `map` expects the function itself.

Another unexpected subtlety of the language which can take us by surprise while we're still not totally familiar with it.

Comment: Interesting! I actually hadn't even considered that ```Nil``` would work as a function, but it makes sense considering ```(1 :: Nil)(0)``` works. "While ```yield``` expects the result of the mapped function, ```map``` expects the function itself." <- Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.